# Ajustar scroll al hacer foco en input para pantallas moviles

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, responsive

pues eso necesito que cuando el usuario de mi web haga foco en uno de los fields de un formulario desde su dispositivo móvil, la.pantalla le haga scroll y posicione su teclado justo debajo del fields, actualmente el teclado tapa el input y eso no se ve bien
[image: así es como se ve en este momento]

Y

[image: así es como se vería mejor para el usuario ya que el teclado no tapa el input]

Answer (score 0):

En este caso, lo que puedes hacer es jugar con `scrollTo()`, `scrollBy()` o `scrollIntoView()`.

Te recomiendo que primero intentes con `scrollBy` y `scrollIntoView`, si ninguno de ambos te funciona, la solución está en implementar `scrollTo()` con una simple fórmula:

> scrollTo( posición de scroll + window offset top de elemento hijo (input) - espacio top )

que implementado en **js** sería así:

```
const elPos = input.getBoundingClientRect().top;
const scrollPos = screen.scrollTop;
screen.scrollTo({top: elPos - scrollPos - 20, behavior: "smooth"});
```

Mira este demo, en este caso he implementado esta fórmula simple y el input siempre queda visible. https://codepen.io/kabal/pen/eYmNLeE